# How to swap controllers in JavaFX? java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, javafx, controller, fxml, scenebuilder

I've checked so for some answers but still didn't got any for few hours now so I'm quite desperate. It's my first try on javafx with scene builder and I'm creating an app with menu and few other screens. I managed to show the menu (first controller) properly, but then when it comes to swapping with other one (after button event) the aplication throws a really long error list in my face and I have no idea why.

Here's the error

```
 Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
... 48 more
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/D:/Projekty/PartyAnimal/bin/view/Rules.fxml:14

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(FXMLLoader.java:103)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:934)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:971)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:220)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:744)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
at controller.MenuController.showRules(MenuController.java:39)
... 58 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil can not access a                                                   member of class controller.RulesController with modifiers ""
at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:102)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:436)
at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(ReflectUtil.java:51)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:927)
... 66 more
```

I start the first controller in my main, showing first fxml window, then I want to swap to the second controller/second FXML after clicking on a button. I guess it's not a problem with fxml cause when I open the second one instead of first one in menu, everything works just fine. The problem  is just in switching the fxmls and controllers. I'm out of ideas.

Main:

```
public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {   
        AnchorPane root = (AnchorPane) FXMLLoader.load(Main.class.getResource("../view/Menu.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,1280,720); 
        primaryStage.setTitle("Party Animal");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

Controller1 - menu:

```
package controller;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;

public class MenuController implements Initializable {


String menu_theme;

public MenuController() {
}
@FXML
public void showRules(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("../view/Rules.fxml"));
     Parent root = loader.load();
     Scene scene = new Scene(root);
     Stage stage = (Stage) ((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
     stage.setTitle("PartyAnimal");
     stage.setScene(scene);
     stage.show();

}}
```

Controller2 - rules:

```
package controller;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;

public class RulesController {

RulesController() {
System.out.println("blablabababa");
}

}
```

Start of fxml1 - menu:

```
<AnchorPane prefHeight="720.0" prefWidth="1280.0" styleClass="pane" stylesheets="@Background.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="controller.MenuController">
    <children>
<Pane prefHeight="720.0" prefWidth="1280.0" styleClass="pane" stylesheets="@Background.css" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <children>
        <Slider id="volumeSlider" layoutX="1147.0" layoutY="681.0" prefHeight="14.0" prefWidth="100.0">
           <effect>
```

Start of fxml2 - rules ( the error at line 14 is the first line here, before these there were just premade imports):

```
<AnchorPane prefHeight="720.0" prefWidth="1280.0" styleClass="pane" stylesheets="@Background.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="controller.RulesController">
   <children>
      <Pane prefHeight="720.0" prefWidth="1280.0" styleClass="pane" stylesheets="@Background.css" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <children>
            <Slider id="volumeSlider" layoutX="1147.0" layoutY="681.0" prefHeight="14.0" prefWidth="100.0">
               <effect>
```

Comment: The referenced line is the first one here of the fxml2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `RulesController` needs a public no-argument constructor.

The `FXMLLoader` will (by default) create the controller by calling the no-argument constructor on the specified class, via reflection. The reflection code assumes that this constructor is public. Since you omitted the `public` keyword from the constructor, the `FXMLLoader` fails when it tries to create the controller.

Just replace

```
RulesController() {
    System.out.println("blablabababa");
}
```

with

```
public RulesController() {
    System.out.println("blablabababa");
}
```

(or delete it entirely, since it isn't doing anything, and the default constructor is public and has the correct signature).

Comment: How could I not notice that! Neither none of my friends did. Thank you so much, I'd spend hours searching for the mistake.